# <a4j:ajax> is not recognised in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I'm using jsf1.2... and in order to use ajax... I've imported ajax4js jar 
but somehow it's throwing error as unknown tag

```
<h:panelGroup style="padding-left:3px">
    <h:commandButton id="submitVisaDetails"
                    value="Submit Request"
                    action="#{VtsIdAutogenerateBB.submitVisaDetails}"
                    onclick="return validateVisaEntries(this,this.form);"
                    styleClass="btn"
                    onmouseover="this.className='btn btnhov'"
                    onmouseout="this.className='btn'" >
          <a4j:ajax execute="@form" />
    </h:commandButton> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are using Richfaces(ajax4jsf) 3 if so its not `<a4j:ajax>` its `<a4j:support>`. Ref: [Ajax Support](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/support.jsf?c=support&tab=usage).

If you are using Richfaces 4 then its only supports JSF 2, so either upgrade to JSF 2 of use Richfaces 3.

Comment: I've imported richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar, but it's not taking any effect

Comment: Did you change the ```<a4j:ajax>``` to ```<a4j:support>```?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace.

Comment: Unknown Tag <a4j:support> in JSF page